# Laravel - Syntax error or access violation in Aggregate Function

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to perform aggregate function and achieve the result shown in the diagrame below:

[image: summary]

New Result:

[image: incorrect result]

I have this query:

```
        $subscribers= Cloudsubscriptions::join("services","cloudsubscriptions.service_name","=","services.name")
            ->join("service_type","services.service_type","=","service_type.id")
            ->select("cloudsubscriptions.service_name"
                    ,"service_type.name as service_type"
                    ,DB::raw("(SELECT count(cloudsubscriptions.id) FROM 'cloudsubscriptions' WHERE 'is_subscribe' = 1) as total_active_users")
                    ,DB::raw("(SELECT count(cloudsubscriptions.id) FROM 'cloudsubscriptions' WHERE 'is_subscribe' = 0) as total_inactive_users")
                    ,DB::raw("(SELECT count(cloudsubscriptions.id) FROM 'cloudsubscriptions') as total_users"))
            ->groupBy("cloudsubscriptions.service_name")
        ->get();
```

I expect to have a result show in the diagram, but I got this error

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''cloudsubscriptions' WHERE 'is_subscribe' = 1) as total_active_users, (SELECT co' at line 1 (SQL: select `cloudsubscriptions`.`service_name`, `service_type`.`name` as `service_type`, (SELECT count(cloudsubscriptions.id) FROM 'cloudsubscriptions' WHERE 'is_subscribe' = 1) as total_active_users, (SELECT count(cloudsubscriptions.id) FROM 'cloudsubscriptions' WHERE 'is_subscribe' = 0) as total_inactive_users, (SELECT count(cloudsubscriptions.id) FROM 'cloudsubscriptions') as total_users from `cloudsubscriptions` inner join `services` on `cloudsubscriptions`.`service_name` = `services`.`name` inner join `service_type` on `services`.`service_type` = `service_type`.`id` group by `cloudsubscriptions`.`service_name` order by `service_name` asc limit 15 offset 0) ◀"

How do I resolve it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the single quotes around table and column names in the raw expressions.

Remove them or use backticks:

```php
$subscribers= Cloudsubscriptions::join("services","cloudsubscriptions.service_name","=","services.name")
    ->join("service_type","services.service_type","=","service_type.id")
    ->select("cloudsubscriptions.service_name"
            ,"service_type.name as service_type"
            ,DB::raw("(SELECT count(cloudsubscriptions.id) FROM `cloudsubscriptions` WHERE `is_subscribe` = 1) as total_active_users")
            ,DB::raw("(SELECT count(cloudsubscriptions.id) FROM `cloudsubscriptions` WHERE `is_subscribe` = 0) as total_inactive_users")
            ,DB::raw("(SELECT count(cloudsubscriptions.id) FROM `cloudsubscriptions`) as total_users"))
    ->groupBy("cloudsubscriptions.service_name")                ^                  ^
->get();
```

Comment: When I did as you advised, the error is no more there but am not getting correct result. Nothing in: 1. Total Active users   2. Total Inactive Users.  Then total users is having the same thing. That is 44 all through, and this is not correct.

Comment: This question is only about the syntax error, please submit a new question.